# How to make Button/Submit to click and change value to null or '' or = nothing in MySQL Database?

Tags: php, sql, database, button

Trying to figure out how to create a button or submit button that changes the value of profile field in that specific user_id in database to nothing, I've used Null and it doesn't seem to be working.
I've created a function. 
Note: Don't worry about the connection because it's there, just in another php file.

```
<?php
function removal($user_id, $removal_one){
$removal_one = '';
$user_id = (int)$user_id;
mysql_query("UPDATE `LogReg` SET `profile` ='". $removal_one ."' WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");

}

$username  = $_GET['username'];
$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
$data = user_data($user_id, 'profile'); 
if(isset($data['profile']) === false && empty($data['profile']) === true){
$removal_one = '';
$update_pic = removal($user_id, $removal_one);
}else{  

    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="remove" value="Remove" type="submit" onclick="'. $update_pic .'"/></form>'
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you put the above query directly in your db?

Comment: I'll give it a try but i don't think it'll recognise the variable $user_id or $removal_one but hold on.

Comment: You do need to remove those... Try it on a dummy user.

Comment: As i predicted, it doesn't recognise $removal_one = '';

Comment: `UPDATE LogReg SET profile = '' WHERE user_id = #` and change # with a number of a dummy user - you can't mix PHP and SQL :-)

Comment: That worked!! Now how to implement that into a button :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your user_id is an integer, you need to pass it to the db as an integer...

Change your query to this:

```
function removal($user_id, $removal_one){
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    mysql_query("UPDATE LogReg SET profile = '' WHERE user_id = $user_id");
}
```

You should put this in a seperate page, so you can call it using JavaScript.
In your code you are mixing PHP and JavaScript, which will not work.

For more information about this, check out [this page on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331718/php-execute-page).

Comment: Thanks for the information! Greatly appreciated. However, how do I create a button that triggers this function, makes it work to remove `profile` field value.

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to use a separate php-page and call that page using JavaScript. I've included a link to where you can find more information about this.

Comment: is it possible to give an example for that javascript call?

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't view the link, but i refreshed and see it now thanks for your help, you're amazing Marty!